# Pandas DataFrame Filter Issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe in pandas. I want to filter out the rows for a specific value in a certain column. This is a single column data frame i.e. 'UPC'.

I am not sure why I am getting `TypeError: invalid type comparision`.

This is what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
output = []
df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", encoding = "latin-1")
rows = (df.loc[df['UPC'] == "00020892103474"])
output.append(len(rows))
```

Comment: what is the dtype of UPC column `df.info()`

Comment: Are you sure UPC isn't being read in as an integer?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it's a string.

Comment: df.info() says:
dtypes: int64(1)
Why is this so?

Comment: Infered type from your excel file, you can `df.loc[df['UPC'].astype(str) == "0000123234"]`  or dtype in read_excel to force a dtype on import.

Comment: What if I have to use a value from another data frame?
e.g. df.loc[df['UPC'].astype(str) == df2.iat[i, 0]]

Comment: Maybe `df.loc[df['UPC'].astype(str) == str(df2.iat[i, 0])` ?